# Anyone using a philosophy-rich dictionary for iPhone?

Tags: discussion, support

I've discovered the iPhone/mobile version of stack exchange a fantastic way to follow my favorite subjects.

A dictionary with more philosophical terms would make the experience even more engaging. Anyone using this feature found a more useful dictionary?